# Change path of forms in a Visual Basic 6 project

Tags: vb6, path, project

I'm trying to modify an old Visual Basic project.  In Visual Basic 6 when I load the project it is saying that the form files aren't in a specific directory instead of looking in the directory where the project is.

I've looked all over the application for where I could set that path, but no luck.

How do you set the path for the project files in Visual Basic 6?

Comment: Short answer: you don't, they are designated/set when a file is first saved using the save dialog.  Longer answer: edit the .VBP file which contains these paths, but you need to know what you are doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the project file (.vbp) with a text editor and edit the path.